# Vimeo API - Is there a way to disable the keyboard shortcuts of the embedded vimeo video?

Tags: iframe, embed, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I often embed the vimeo video via `iframe` into my website for video conferencing.
I can easily hide the control bar by query string like below.

`https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678?controls=0`

However, this method only hides the control bar but doesn't disable the shortcuts.

Is there a way to disable the keyboard shortcuts of the embedded Vimeo video?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

at the moment the only way to disable shortcuts is to make video as background.

Use this querystring: ?background=1&muted=0&loop=0&responsive=1

Best regards
Stefano

Comment: I am sorry that my purpose wasn't clear. I need to disable all shortcuts except the shortcuts "F" and "space". Is there a way to disable some shortcuts instead of all?

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyboard=false` param to disable keyboard input:

> Whether to enable keyboard input to trigger player events. This setting doesn't affect tab control.

Source: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/embed

Comment: I am sorry that my purpose wasn't clear. I need to disable all shortcuts except the shortcuts "F" and "space". Is there a way to disable some shortcuts instead of all?